# Json data extraction using python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this python script that gives me results from an API query:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://zabbix.enterprise.net/zabbix/api_jsonrpc.php'

token = '6e..5d'

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

get_hosts_payload = {
    'jsonrpc': '2.0',
    'method': 'host.get',
    'params': {
        'output': 'extend',
        'selectTags': 'extend'
    },
    'auth': token,
    'id': 1
}

response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(get_hosts_payload), headers=headers)

# Process response
if response.status_code == 200:
    result = response.json()['result']
    for host in result:
        print(host)
        print('Host Name:', host['name'])
        print('Description:', host['description'])
#???    print('Tag:', host['tags': {'tag': 'parent'}])
else:
    print('Request failed with status code:', response.status_code)
```

inside the for loop, the `print(host)` gives me this (which is fine):

```
{'hostid': '200200000066897', 'proxy_hostid': '200200000029657', 'host': 'kar-xt-ont-1.enterprise.net', 'status': '0', 'lastaccess': '0', 'ipmi_authtype': '-1', 'ipmi_privilege': '2', 'ipmi_username': '', 'ipmi_password': '', 'maintenanceid': '100100000025359', 'maintenance_status': '1', 'maintenance_type': '0', 'maintenance_from': '1684875600', 'name': 'kar-xt-ont-1', 'flags': '0', 'templateid': '0', 'description': 'ONT:1/1/1/1/11', 'tls_connect': '1', 'tls_accept': '1', 'tls_issuer': '', 'tls_subject': '', 'proxy_address': '', 'auto_compress': '1', 'custom_interfaces': '0', 'uuid': '', 'inventory_mode': '1', 'tags': [{'tag': 'priority', 'value': '3'}, {'tag': 'escalation', 'value': 'network'}, {'tag': 'location', 'value': 'KAR'}, {'tag': 'parent', 'value': 'KAR-XT(PON:1/1/1/1)'}]}
{'hostid': '200200000065228', 'proxy_hostid': '200200000023737', 'host': 'kar-xt-ont-2.enterprise.net', 'status': '0', 'lastaccess': '0', 'ipmi_authtype': '-1', 'ipmi_privilege': '2', 'ipmi_username': '', 'ipmi_password': '', 'maintenanceid': '100100000025359', 'maintenance_status': '1', 'maintenance_type': '0', 'maintenance_from': '1684875600', 'name': 'kar-xt-ont-2', 'flags': '0', 'templateid': '0', 'description': 'ONT:1/1/1/1/12', 'tls_connect': '1', 'tls_accept': '1', 'tls_issuer': '', 'tls_subject': '', 'proxy_address': '', 'auto_compress': '1', 'custom_interfaces': '0', 'uuid': '', 'inventory_mode': '1', 'tags': [{'tag': 'priority', 'value': '3'}, {'tag': 'escalation', 'value': 'network'}, {'tag': 'location', 'value': 'KAR'}, {'tag': 'parent', 'value': 'KAR-XT(PON:1/1/1/1)'}]}
```

I can extract piece of data from this result with the second and third `print()`

```
Host Name: kar-xt-ont-1
Description: ONT:1/1/1/1/11
Host Name: kar-xt-ont-2
Description: ONT:1/1/1/1/12
```

But I would like to get the value of the 'section' (don't know if it is called 'section') tags, especially the from the tag 'parent'. I have tried many combinations but no success.

I have no idea on how to search for the answer, so I would thank any clues.

The desired result would be like this:

```
Host Name: kar-xt-ont-1
Description: ONT:1/1/1/1/11
Parent: KAR-XT(PON:1/1/1/1)

Host Name: kar-xt-ont-2
Description: ONT:1/1/1/1/12
Parent: KAR-XT(PON:1/1/1/1)
```

Comment: `next(item['value'] for item in host['tags'] if item['tag'] == 'parent')`

Comment: `next(item['value'] for item in host['tags'] if item['tag'] == 'parent')` This worked as I wanted. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -2):

```
print("Parent: ", next(tag for tag in host["tags"] if tag["tag"] == "parent")["value"])
```